# Thread seems to magically start

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have an issue with thread while working with Android studio.
Here is my thread class :

```
class MainLoop extends Thread {


    private boolean run = true;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread started");
        run = true;

        final double SPF = 1.0/2.0;
        double deltaS;
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        long newTime;

        while(run) {
            newTime = System.nanoTime();
            deltaS = (float)(newTime-lastTime)/1000000000f;
            if (deltaS > SPF) {
                lastTime = newTime;
                System.out.println("Hello from thread");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Thread killed");
    }

    void kill() {
        System.out.println("Killing thread");
        run = false;
    }

}
```

And here is my MainActivity class :

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


        private MainLoop mainLoop = null;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mainLoop = new MainLoop();
            mainLoop.start();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            mainLoop = new MainLoop();
            mainLoop.start();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            mainLoop.kill();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And here is the output I have :

```
08-15 12:24:07.480 2581-2667/com.lteii.hello I/System.out: Hello from thread
08-15 12:24:07.593 2581-2671/com.lteii.hello I/System.out: Hello from thread
08-15 12:24:07.595 2581-2581/com.lteii.hello D/ViewRootImpl@e1e91f8[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
08-15 12:24:07.596 2581-2581/com.lteii.hello W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/framework/QPerformance.jar
08-15 12:24:07.597 2581-2581/com.lteii.hello E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
08-15 12:24:07.597 2581-2581/com.lteii.hello V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = null
08-15 12:24:07.598 2581-2581/com.lteii.hello I/System.out: Killing thread
08-15 12:24:07.598 2581-2671/com.lteii.hello I/System.out: Thread killed
08-15 12:24:07.622 2581-2581/com.lteii.hello I/System.out: Killing thread
08-15 12:24:07.724 2581-2581/com.lteii.hello I/System.out: Killing thread
08-15 12:24:07.746 2581-2581/com.lteii.hello I/System.out: Killing thread
08-15 12:24:07.758 2581-2581/com.lteii.hello I/System.out: Killing thread
08-15 12:24:07.760 2581-2581/com.lteii.hello D/ViewRootImpl@e1e91f8[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
08-15 12:24:07.760 2581-2581/com.lteii.hello I/System.out: Killing thread
08-15 12:24:07.980 2581-2667/com.lteii.hello I/System.out: Hello from thread
08-15 12:24:08.480 2581-2667/com.lteii.hello I/System.out: Hello from thread
```

I don't understand how it is possible, apparently the onResume() method restarts the thread everytime i kill it with the onTouchEvent() method, since when I delete onResume(), I don't see anymore "Hello from thread" after "Thread killed"
Anyway I should see "Thread created" between "Thread killed" and "Hello from thread"
I need help!

Comment: @Enzokie is right, it's because `onResume()` get's called when `onCreate()` is called, thus only the instance created last is stored and can be killed.

Comment: Oh thank you! I deleted the two lines creating and starting the thread from onCreate(), now it works perfectly! Let me mark this question as resolved ;)

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MainLoop mainLoop = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (mainLoop == null) {
            mainLoop = new MainLoop();
            mainLoop.start();
        } else {
            System.out.println("onCreate: Thread has not been killed!");
        } 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mainLoop == null) {
            mainLoop = new MainLoop();
            mainLoop.start();
        } else {
            System.out.println("onResume: Thread has not been killed!");
        } 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (mainLoop != null) {
            mainLoop.kill();
            mainLoop = null;
        } else {
            System.out.println("onTouchEvent: Thread has not been created!");
        }
        return false;
    }
```

That should explain the issue. It is in general good practice to double-check your own code. In the best case those double-checks will never be called, in worst case you know why things are going wrong.

As a side-note: the thread you created runs in an infinite loop, so it will drain the battery very fast by doing nothing. At a minimum use `Thread.sleep` or better use a `ScheduledExecutor`, or `Timer` if you only ever have one thread.

Comment: You forgot to null check your `mainLoop.kill()`, triggering `onTouchEvent` twice will throw `NullPointerException` :)

Comment: this is valid as long as it is granted that onCreate, onResume and onTouchEvent cannot be called concurrently. Otherwise, you will be face race conditions (not saying this is happening since i don't know specific android behaviour; pointing it out just in case).

Comment: @albert_nil if Android starts calling onResume/onCreate concurrently, I am pretty sure that most applications will stop working properly. So it is a safe bet that this is not happening anytime soon.

Comment: i was more afraid of the onTouchEvent in case there is no grant that one event can be received before the previous one handling finishes (but as said don't know details of android behaviour), so if you are sure of that, evertything is fine :)

Comment: The event bus is not threaded either for the same reason. Android and its API was build for single-CPU phones initially. Also no threading makes it a lot easier for the common developer to write an App.

Comment: `run` has to be volatile.

Comment: `volatile` is not necessary in this context. It would ensure that the thread is stopped at the beginning of the next loop immediately after the variable has been set, but since there is no guarantee in which state the thread is, there is no guarantee that it will terminate immediately even with volatile. That effectively makes volatile pointless in this particular case.

Comment: `volatile` ensures that `MainLoop` will terminate at all. Without it(or other memory synchronization mechanism) if you call `mainLoop.kill();` from a different thread `run` can remain forever `true` in `MainLoop` thread.

Comment: Cached values of threads are updated eventually when it is convenient for the CPU, volatile only ensures that it happens immediately. But even without it will happen sooner or later. In worst-case scenarios it can take a few more milliseconds, but if - as you say - the CPU would never update it's memory cache, then a lot of things would be broken or pointlessly complicated.